# C typedef struct uncertainty

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Consider the following typedef struct in C:

```
21:typedef struct source{
22: double  ds;             //ray step
23: double  rx,zx;          //source coords
24: double  rbox1, rbox2;   //the box that limits the range of the rays
25: double  freqx;          //source frequency
26:    int64_t  nThetas;        //number of launching angles
27:    double   theta1, thetaN; //first and last launching angle
28:}source_t;
```

I get the error:
    globals.h:21: error: redefinition of 'struct source'
    globals.h:28: error: conflicting types for 'source_t'
    globals.h:28: note: previous declaration of 'source_t' was here

I've tried using other formats for this definition:

```
struct source{
...
};
typedef struct source source_t;
```

and

```
typedef struct{
...
}source_t;
```

Which both return the same error.
Why does this happen? it looks perfectly right to me.

Comment: looks like the "globals.h" file gets included twice from the source files

Comment: works perfectly for me: http://ideone.com/kKj8q

Comment: based on SirDarius' comment: have you set up a **reinclude protection** in `globals.h`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't include your header twice (without using `#ifndef`/`#pragma once` to avoid that)?
Even if there'd been some mistake in your construct it shouldn't trigger the error "redefinition of '...'" cause it's the very first line?

Comment: Yeah, was including a file [that included a file (repeat a couple of times)] that included globals.h. Used `#pragma once` and it did wonders. _Way_ cleaner that writing include guards. Thanks!

Comment: Please use both - `#pragma`s are compiler-specific.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that your header file is being included more than once.
You need to ensure that if this happens, the typedef is only executed once.

You can do this by wrapping globals.h with:

```
  #ifndef _globals_h_
  #define _globals_h_
  [...]
  #endif
```

Comment: Please do not start your include symbol name with an underscore. Such names are reserved for use by the standard library implementation. (There are some exceptions, but it's better not to play with fire.) It's also normal to use all-caps for everything that's fed to the preprocessor, so `GLOBALS_H` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

The errors say a `struct source` has been defined more than once.

Maybe you included the header file twice?

Just to be on the safe side, be sure that your header gets only included once: put

```
#ifndef YOUR_HEADER_FILE_NAME
#define YOUR_HEADER_FILE_NAME
```

at the beginning, and

```
#endif
```

at the end of your header file: this will prevent it to be included twice or more by any source file.